# Invoke Method But Code Doesn't Go Respextively

Tags: java, android

I have some problem and I put somewhere Log.D for seeing which line is work and which lines isn't work. But `Log.d("look","22222222222222222");` doesn't work.

I have a `fill()` method. And I invoke this method in `onCreate()` method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_screen);        
    Log.d("look","00000000000000000");
    fill(typeC);
   Log.d("look","444444444444444444");                
}
```

Let see, implementation of `fill()` method.

```
private void search(final String [] list) {
    Log.d("look","1111111111111111111");
    for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){
        DatabaseReference fd = mDatabase.child(list[i]);
        fd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren() ;
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterable.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = iterator.next();
                    Product product = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Product.class);
                    Log.d("look","222222222222222222222222");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        Log.d("look","333333333333333333333333");
    }
}
```

And I run the program. I saw this LogCat output respectively:

```
D/look: 00000000000000000
D/look: 1111111111111111111
D/look: 333333333333333333333333
D/look: 333333333333333333333333
D/look: 333333333333333333333333
D/look: 444444444444444444
```

And You can see there is no `D/look: 222222222222222`. Why that line doesn't work?

Comment: `dataSnapshot` probably has no children, that's why the iterator is empty, which leads to the `while` not being executed

Answer (score 0):

If this line is never executed, it means you don't enter in the while-loop. Which means iterator does not have next. Probably because snapshotIterable has no children.